# Closed Subgroups of Lie Groups are closed Lie Subgroups?

Tags: differential-geometry

I found this theorem in a differential geometry textbook: "An abstract subgroup H of a Lie group G is a regular submanifold and hence a closed Lie subgroup if and only if H is a closed set in G."

How could this be true? What if H were a discrete group? Then there would be no way it could even be a manifold, let alone a Lie group.

Comment: Discrete spaces are zero dimensional manifolds